# Array throwing nulls instead of Strings

Tags: java

This array gets a parameter from a bunch of words stored in another array.

If the array has 6 spaces but only has 4 words in it, the new array must downsize to those 4 spaces, to put an example.
If the array has 6 spaces and no words in it, the array must be filled with 4 spaces with the String "Not Found".

The problem I'm having is that the array is throwing nulls instead of putting "Not found".

What can it be the problem?

```
    public static void getAllSynonyms(String[][] matrix, String wordToBeFound) {
    int arrayLenght = 0;
    String synonyms[] = new String[matrix[0].length];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {

            if (matrix[i][j].equals(wordToBeFound)) {
                for (int k = 0; k < matrix[0].length; k++) {

                    if (!matrix[i][k].equals("")) {
                        synonyms[i] = matrix[i][k];

                    } else {
                        arrayLenght = matrix[0].length - 1;
                        synonyms[i] = "Not Found";
                        int counter = 0;
                        counter++;
                    }
                    System.out.println("" + synonyms[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    String synonymsArray[] = new String[arrayLenght];


    for (int i = 0; i <synonyms.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(""+ synonyms[i]);

            if (synonyms[i] != "Not Found") {
            synonymsArray[counter2++] = synonyms[i];

            }


        }

    }
```

The nulls appear in the second System.out.

This is the matrix.

```
String[][] matrix = {{"joe", "slim", "ed", "george"},
    {"soto", "", "asdrubal", ""},
    {"billy", "sanchez", "carlos", "fernando"}};
```

Comment: include the code from where you pass matrix array.I suspect you dint initialize it

Comment: you have an empty matix!

Comment: Besides a lot of other problems, j cycle uses [0] matrix line.

Answer (score 0):

matrix.length =3, but matrix[0].length =4

as you iterate in the most outer loop until matrix.length, but initialized synonyms with String[matrix[0].length], synonyms[3] is never reached and therefor null

edit:
so in this rows of your matrix your searchWord can't be found and you never set synonyms[i]. you set it only in the block

```
if (matrix[i][j].equals(wordToBeFound)) {
```

but if this is false, then your synonyms array is never modified

Comment: The positons 0,1 and 2 are the ones that are null